# I would like to translate an english curse into proper latin

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

I would like to translate this english curse into latin.

"Whoever takes my freedom will burn in hell forever."

Comment: What are the details of this curse? Are you stating this as a fact ("this is what will happen") or as a wish ("may this happen")? Who is using it?

Answer (score 6):

There are a variety of ways to translate this, but I would go with:

> *Quīcumque lībertātem meam abripiat, flammīs ācribus addīcatur.*
>   Whosoever might take away my liberty shall be consigned to the piercing flames.

(The marks over the vowels represent different sounds that merged together in later Latin; if you're going for an Ecclesiastical style, like your tag indicates, feel free to leave them off.)

- *Quīcumque* is a masculine singular pronoun: "whoever". It's conventional to use the masculine in Latin if you don't know the gender of the person, but if you're more worried about a woman taking your freedom than a man, you could use *quaecumque*.
- *Lībertātem* is "freedom", plain and simple.
- *Meam* is "my", in the feminine accusative to agree with *lībertātem*.
- *Abripiat* is a subjunctive from *abripiō*, "to tear away by force".
- *Flammīs* is "flames", dative.
- *Ācribus* is "piercing", also dative.
- *Addīcatur* is the passive subjunctive of *addīcō*, "to consign".
- The two present subjunctives here are something like "if anyone should…then may they…".
- I'm not very familiar with phrases for Hell in Ecclesiastical Latin, so the second half of the phrase is borrowed from verse 16 of the Dies Irae: *cōnfūtātīs maledictīs flammīs ācribus addictīs, vocā mē cum benedictīs* "with the damned having been silenced [and] consigned to the piercing flames, call me with the blessed".

EDIT: If you want to state it as a fact ("this will happen") you can use the simple future rather than the subjunctive.

> *Quīcumque lībertātem meam **abripiet**, flammīs ācribus **addīcētur**.*
>   Whosoever will take away my liberty, he will be consigned to the piercing flames.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I want it to be stated as a fact. Also, if there's any differences between masculine and feminine forms, I would like to see it in masculine form.

Comment: Sorry,  I'm the original asker but accidentally logged in under this account.

Comment: @BlueSteel Added an option for that